# использование dota2api

Tags: python, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте.
недавно заинтересовался вопросом использования dota2api. Как я понял, работает оно через тот же stamApi, просто другой набор функций.
Dota2api реализована на [питоне](https://dota2api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Cреди предоставляемых функций Апи, есть функция:

```
api.get_match_details(match_id=<*match_ID*>)
```

так вот эта функция возвращает довольно большой объем данных, среди которых есть  "account_id":21265941 - это внутриигровой идентификатор пользователя.

Вопрос: **Как по "account_id" можно узнать stam_id?**